# Failed to start Tomcat server

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

[jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9993.png)> I tried to run my tomcat server and the error below shown in console.

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/B-SITE-DIARY]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component  [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/B-SITE-DIARY]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
... 6 more
```

> I tried to look other solution that having the same problem as me, but it still cannot be resolved. Anyone that can help me?

I use **Tomcat 7.0 version** and **jdk 1.7**

I tried run tomcat without any project file, and it cannot be started. Does it means my Tomcat server or Java has problem?

Comment: What version of tomcat server you are using

Comment: sorry. forgot to metion. already updated. i use version 7.0

Comment: try by removing server instance and create again

Comment: already do it but the result is still the same

Comment: please show me your list of jars

Comment: This error message is useless. This is just a summary error message that Tomcat failed to start. There are a gazillion of possible underlying causes. It doesn't make sense to get people doing shoots in the dark. The real cause is visible further back in the server log. You should focus on the root cause of the exception, not on the summary cause. The root cause of the exception represents the answer to your problem. Fix your question to show the root cause of the exception instead of the summary cause.

Comment: I am really sorry. I am asking because I really do not know what to do. But thanks for the suggestion. I will update the question

Answer (score -1):

I think your webapp contain servletcontainer specific libraries like servlet-api.jar file in its /WEB-INF/lib.Please remove it all and it should only contain webapp specific libraries,not to the servletcontainer.it will conflict with your server.

Comment: I did not put any servlet-api. jar or any similar with that.

Comment: please click at the link in my post

Comment: [Plagiarism is very rude](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do). In the future, when you're incapable of answering off top of head and you thus copy an existing answer or whatever source found in the world wide web, put it in a quote block and mention the source. Better is to just post a comment and/or vote for close as duplicate.